# get rms level reduced data in ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to get audio RMS level for an audio using the following command

```
.\ffprobe -f lavfi -i amovie=testing.m4a,astats=metadata=0:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level:stream_tags:format_tags -of csv=p=0 -show_format -count_frames -show_streams -show_data -print_format json > something.json
```

I am able to receive the json. but the issue is am getting approximately 340 datas for just a 7 second audio, how to reduce this? I have tried changing the `reset` value to less than 1 but it shows 350000 data. please help

Comment: How frequently do you want the audio?

Comment: @Gyan: I need 20 data for a second, now its proving 48 data per second

Answer (score 3):

astats will produce output for each audio frame, and that can't change. However, you can change audio frame size so that 20 number of frames are present per second.

`.\ffprobe -f lavfi -i amovie=testing.m4a,aresample=50000,asetnsamples=2500,astats=metadata=0:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level:stream_tags:format_tags -of csv=p=0 -show_format -count_frames -show_streams -show_data -print_format json > something.json`

Comment: This should be the validated answer